# Sub-menu does not showing up despite "expandend" option is on

Tags: 8, navigation

I have an menu that has some sub-menu:
[image]

For the top option of sub-menu I've selected "expanded" option:
[image]

My `.twig` for menu looks like this:

```
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <div {{ attributes.addClass(['tree', 'ul', 'level0']) }}>
    {% else %}
      <div class="tree ul sub level-{{ menu_level }}">
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
        <div class="li">
            <a href="{{ item.url }}" {% if item.in_active_trail %}class="active"{% endif %}>{{ item.title }}<span class="indicator"></span></a>
            {% if item.below %}
                {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

But I don't get sub-menu in output (`item.below` always returns false).
I've clear the cache via admin panel. I don't see sub-menu output with default `menu--main.html.twig` either.